# Test class for automation with Quip documents

Tags: unit-test, quip

I have a Trigger automation that creates a mirror record when a quip document is created in salesforce.
It was using hardcoded URLs and we are migrating to a different domain, so we had to change it, taking the opportunity to move it from hardcoded to manageable settings(Custom metadata in this case).
This mirror record contains only basic information such as *Title, Quip document link*, and *Document Owner*.
This Object is needed because even as a Quip admin and the "unredacted access" permission enabled it is not possible to have direct access to documents.

To prevent this mirror record to be created when any document is inserted it checks the *FileType* field on the *ContentVersion* for **QUIPDOC**.

```
for(ContentVersion data : lstContVersion){
    if (data.FileType == 'QUIPDOC') {
        lstQuipMirror.add(generateMirror(data));
    }
}
```

What I have tried:

1. set *PathOnclient* to the same as an existing Quip file, and the filetype was set to **UNKNOWN**
2. I've set the *ExternalDocumentInfo1* whit a real Quip URL and also no luck.

What I knew would not work (but have tried anyways):

- set *Filetype* on contentversion (Not writeable).

This is a pre-existing development from other teams that worked with the same client, and the if and its internal logic wore set on a single line, for test coverage:

```
for(ContentVersion data : lstContVersion){
    if (data.FileType == 'QUIPDOC') {Quip_Mirror__c quipmirror = new Quip_Mirror__c(); quipmirror .Title__c = data.Tile; /*...*/ lstQuipMirror.add(quipmirror);}
}
```

I think I would need to work with *ExternalDataSources* but found no good examples of how to work with it in test classes.

At this point, I'm almost returning the class to its original crap* indentation ad lack of test just o I can get this off my shoulders, but I won't be able to sleep well at night doing so. (Oh yes, I am being overdramatic here).

Thank you all for your help on this.

PS.: this also has a flow execution on the mirror object that shares the Quip doc with a group of people based on several different criteria, it uses the doc link in the mirror record to do so.
I'll, probably, face a new issue related to this flow after solving this "if" problem

Comment: Your query for ContentVersion should be moved into a selector class ; then using dependency injection, the test method injects a mock selector that returns a list of ContentVersion sobjects (not DML'd). These can be mocked using the JSON serialize/deserialize technique to get around the field not writeable issue

Comment: Thanks for the help. § This is similar to an idea that I had before. § I tend to avoid mocking this kind of thinking because if not done properly it can interfere with different tests in the org, related to the same object, but looks like this is the only option

Comment: dependency injection can be done on a testmethod-by-testmethod basis; when coupled with the UnitofWork pattern, you can even dependency inject the DML updates done by the code-under-test

Answer (score 0):

A colleague and I were working on this (via data migration, not apex) and guessed our way into a solution. For some reason, when Quip doc `ContentVersion` records are created in the *standard* way, there is a secret handshake and the `PathOnClient` attribute does not include a file extension, but `FileType` populates fine.

#### The solution: add ".quipdoc" to the original `PathOnClient`.

So strange. Again, this worked in a data load context, so I cannot be sure about apex.

Now, we are trying to figure out what to do to get `FileType = "QUIPCHAT"`...

---

As for the design pattern approach, it looks like you have more help there.

Comment: I am working on a different subject related to ContentDocument/Links, I'll try this when updating the test class, thanks for the tip